# Eclipse Mars blurs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

After working with Eclipse Luna for a few years I decided to migrate to Mars. I noticed that when I move to the right with the h-scroll it becomes blurred.

I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 in a laptop Compaq 6710b.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 10):

This might be due to the change from GTK 2 in Luna to GTK 3 in Mars

Try putting the lines:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

in your 'eclipse.ini' file (must be **before** any '-vmargs' line) and the words must be on separate lines.

A bit more detail in Eclipse bug [470944](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470944)