# Strange behavior of an Eclipse IDE while moving through a text. (C++ IDE)

Tags: eclipse, ide

I got an Eclipse IDE and I found it really frustrating to move through a text. I'm using Apricity OS which is a derivative of an Arch Linux.

The version of an Eclipse is Neon but whatever version did I download I receive the same Error.

Eclipse IDE was downloaded from their website, I know that I could find it in Aur but I found it even more buggy.

I think that the best way to tell you what is a problem is to show you the problem. 
[Photo](https://s24.postimg.org/5wpuqkbmt/1460880820281-824493228.jpg)

Please forgive me the photo from a phone and it's quality but I was unable to catch the problem using shutter or even other screenshot tools.

I spent couple of hours on Google but I did not found an answer, so you are my last hope.

Comment: It might be a variant of the problem described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31361719/2670892)

Comment: Well it does not works unfortunately :(